# Generate automatic unique number in database

Tags: c#, asp.net

On a database I have a table with 8 columns and 7 columns are about user details. Now I need to save one unique number in that one column.
I generate one form in that form i have 8 textboxes for enter details of user and on button click its goes database to save.i need when i click on button to create new user then on first textbox that code is generate in textbox and on save button click it goes to save in database.i dont want to use primary key.

how to generate the automatic code
how to automatic display in entry mode form.
and on save button click its go to databse

Comment: you should use primary key

Comment: originally i dont want to use primary key

Comment: you did not mention what database store you are using

Comment: Should the ID be generated by code or by the database?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly and you are intending to generate a unique number from the form, prior to the database insert? How about using a GUID:

```
Guid g;
g = Guid.NewGuid();
```

Update the first textbox to show the GUID immediately and then pull it through on your database insert when the user hits save.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL Server you could set the column to type UNIQUEIDENTIFIER

[MS Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

[ If  **id**  is *numerical*, then follow these steps: ]

*(Base of identity concept)*

---

First calculate ***sum*** of the **id** column values, say Y

```
Y = SUM(id)
```

Then increase Y one unit:

```
Y = Y + 1
```

Now store Y to **id** column for new user.

> Absolutely Y will be unique (as primary key).